# Convert to prper format

Tags: arrays, format, json

How can i convert following json to required format?

What I have :

```
{
  "1":{
    "name":"Room1",
    "agegroup":"38 to 67",
    "display_agegroup":"Months",
    "0":"After School Care"
  },
  "5":{
     "name":"new room",
     "agegroup":"3.08 to 4.",
     "display_agegroup":"Years",
     "0":"After School Care",
     "1":"Before School Care"
  }
}
```

What I need:

```
[{
   "id":"1",
   "field1":"Room1",
   "field2":"38 to 67",
   "field3":"Months",
   "field4":"After School Care"},
 {
   "id":"5",
   "field1":"new room",
   "field2":"3.08 to 4.",
   "field3":"Years",
   "field4":"After School Care & Before School Care"
}]
```

Please guide me.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Hint: use [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys).

Comment: yes tried but no result.

Answer (score 0):

```
var out = [];
var input = {
  "1": { /* ... */ },
  "5": { /* ... */ }
};

_.each(_.keys(input), function(el) {
  var obj = {
    "id": el
  };

  _.each(_.keys(input[el], function(k, idx) {
    obj["field"+(1+idx)] = input[el][k];
  });

  out.push(obj);
});
```

for convenience this uses [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) .  If you can't/won't, then it's pretty trivial to replace `_.keys` and `_.each` with standard JS code.